# In Word, is there a way to increase the size of the triangles used to collapse and expand headings?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm using Office 365. Is there a way to increase the size of the triangles used to collapse and expand headings? They don't have an expanded click area, so you have to click right on the triangle, which is small and easy to miss. This is hardest when using a touchpad since it's not precise enough to quickly get the cursor onto such a small area.

Comment: Other than making your overall scale larger (Windows 10 recent versions), I don't think so. Can you use a Bluetooth Mouse (or USB Mouse) as these are vastly more accurate than touch pads.

Comment: A mouse is not the best solution for me, but I'll keep it in mind if it's the only way.